# Run JSON while typing in textbox in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I need to get the value of textbox as I type, and perform a function of JSON, I tried doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#<%= txtBusca.ClientID %>").keypress(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: "{ 'valor' : '" + $(this).val() + "'}",
      url: "Especialidades.aspx/Buscar",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function () {
        alert('OK');
      }
    })
   });
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest to add a delay to the keypress event. You can see how we implenmented this in our search bar here: http://www.onmeda.de/ .. the uncompressed source of the js is available here: https://github.com/keanan/OnmedaJS

Comment: just a note, if you want to get the latest value of the textbox to submit, rather use keyup instead of keypress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the line below is causing the problem

```
data: "{ 'valor' : '" + $(this).val() + "'}",
```

The reason is **this**    keyword. In your code it is referring ajax context.

I recommend you to assign this into variable before Ajax call blocks and refer it inside like the following :

```
$("#<%= txtBusca.ClientID %>").keypress(function () {

var enteredValue=$(this).val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: { 'valor' : enteredValue },
```

Answer (score 0):

You've wrapped the data-object with double quotes, try removing them:

```
data: { 'valor' : $(this).val() }
```